# How do I skip a Maven plugin execution if "-DskipTests" or "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" is specified?

Tags: maven, testing, plugins, automated-tests

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I have this plugin, which normally I want to run before my JUnit tests are executed:

```xml
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <test.mysql.db.user>sbjunituser</test.mysql.db.user>
            <test.mysql.db.password></test.mysql.db.password>
            <test.mysql.db.prefix>sbjunit</test.mysql.db.prefix>
            <test.mysql.db.sid>${test.mysql.db.prefix}_${project.artifactId}</test.mysql.db.sid>
            <test.mysql.db.host>localhost</test.mysql.db.host>
            <test.mysql.db.port>3306</test.mysql.db.port>
            <test.mysql.dataSource.url>jdbc:mysql://${test.mysql.db.host}:${test.mysql.db.port}/${test.mysql.db.sid}</test.mysql.dataSource.url>
            <test.mysql.dataSource.driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</test.mysql.dataSource.driverClassName>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
        <!--  Run the liquibase scripts -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.18</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-database</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://${test.mysql.db.host}:${test.mysql.db.port}/${test.mysql.db.sid}</url>
                        <username>${test.mysql.db.user}</username>
                        <password>${test.mysql.db.password}</password>
                        <changeLogFile>${project.build.directory}/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However, if someone specifies `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` or `-DskipTests`, I would like to skip this plugin from running.  How do I do that?  I tried changing the execution phase to "test", but then my unit tests get run before this plugin, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use profiles that get activated when using one of the unit test skip properties to set a new property (e.g. `skipLiquibaseRun`) that holds the flag if liquibase should run or not

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipLiquibaseRun>false</skipLiquibaseRun>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>skipTestCompileAndRun</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>maven.test.skip</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipLiquibaseRun>true</skipLiquibaseRun>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>skipTestRun</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>skipTests</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipLiquibaseRun>true</skipLiquibaseRun>
      </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Use the new property in the liquibase plugin section to decide if the run should be [skipped](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven_update#skip), like this:

```xml
<configuration>
    <skip>${skipLiquibaseRun}</skip>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://${test.mysql.db.host}:${test.mysql.db.port}/${test.mysql.db.sid}</url>
    <username>${test.mysql.db.user}</username>
    <password>${test.mysql.db.password}</password>
    <changeLogFile>${project.build.directory}/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
</configuration>
```

Not tested, but hope it works ;-)

Answer (score 34):

This worked for me:

```
<configuration>
   <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
</configuration>
```

**OR**

```
<configuration>
   <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the most straight-forward way is to cascade the "skip" properties in your POM:

```
<properties>
  <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
  <skipTests>${maven.test.skip}</skipTests>
  <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
</properties>
```

Then you can use the last "skip" property set above in your plugin's configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
</configuration>
```

See [Maven Failsafe Plugin: Skipping Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html) for more details on each of the different "skip" properties mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Nice! This is the only answer I've found that handles both maven.test.skip and skipTests.

Comment: The link to the failsafe plugin documentation is broken.

Answer (score 6):

For plugins that **do not support `skip`** in the configuration there is another hacky way to **skip without the use of profiles.**

In the phase declaration you can append an attribute `pluginxyz.skip`

e.g.

```xml
<properties>
   <property>
      <pluginxyz.skip><pluginxyz.skip>
   </property>     
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>build-database</id>
        <phase>process-test-classes${pluginxyz.skip}</phase>
        <configuration>....</configuration>
     </execution>
<plugin>
```

Then when executing from the command line you can add `-Dpluginxyz.skip=true` which will append the `true` value to the phase name.

Since there is no phase called `process-test-classestrue` the goal will not be executed.

Comment: It will not work for -Dpluginxyz.skip=false

Comment: @BartoszMiller I never said that it will. It is indeed a hacky way, but it does the job.

Comment: @BartoszMiller But it _does_ work for `-Dpluginxyz.skip=false`! It will skip the tests like you wanted because you gave it a value!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding it to a profile like the example below, (however, this will only work for the cases when `maven.test.skip` is not specified:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>execute-liquibase</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!maven.test.skip</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!--  Run the liquibase scripts -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1</version>
                    <dependencies>
                       <dependency>
                           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                           <version>5.1.18</version>
                       </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>build-database</id>
                           <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                           <configuration>
                               <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                               <url>jdbc:mysql://${test.mysql.db.host}:${test.mysql.db.port}/${test.mysql.db.sid}</url>
                               <username>${test.mysql.db.user}</username>
                               <password>${test.mysql.db.password}</password>
                               <changeLogFile>${project.build.directory}/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
                               <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                           </configuration>
                           <goals>
                              <goal>update</goal>
                           </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
 <profiles>
```

Comment: My code was already part of a profile.  I like your solution, but I don't want to ignore everything being executed in my profile.

Comment: Well, then I guess you should further describe your problem, as that doesn't become immediately clear. Perhaps you could provide some more details.

Comment: My problem is -- I want to prevent the plugin (listed in the question) from executing if someone specifies "-Dmaven.test.skip=true" or "-DskipTests".  I included the complete plugin info and the profile it appears within in my question.  Let me know what other details you'd like me to include.

Comment: This is REALLY good for plugins that do not implement some skip functionality.  You're stepping outside these plugins and taking control at a higher level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done directly, but you can add `-Dliquibase.should.run=false` to skip liquibase entirely (see http://www.liquibase.org/manual/maven_update#skip). You can bundle this property and `skipTests` into a separate profile if you don't want to type both.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>skipTestAndDb</id>
        <properties>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            <liquibase.should.run>false</liquibase.should.run>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you would just type `mvn install -PskipTestAndDb`

Comment: You made up the "liquibase.should.run" property, right?  How do you make that property mean that the plugin doesn't run?  What code do you have to add to the liquibase plugin execution?